# How to cherry pick ZIP contents with Gradle Distribution plugin?

Tags: plugins, configuration, gradle, zip

My Gradle build currently produces the following directory structure under a `build` dir in my project root:

```
myapp/
    src/
    build.gradle
    build/
        docs/
            groovydoc/* (all Groovydocs)
        libs/
            myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar
            myapp-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
        reports/
            codenarc/
                main.html
        test-results/* (JUnit test results)
```

I would like to add the [`distribution` plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html) (or anything that accomplishes my goals, really) to have Gradle produce a ZIP file with the following directory structure:

```
myapp-SNAPSHOT-buildreport.zip/
    tests/
        (JUnit tests from build/test-results above)
    reports/
        main.html (CodeNarc report from build/reports/codenarc above)
    api/
        (Groovydocs from build/docs above)
    source/
        myapp-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar (from build/libs above)
    bin/
        myapp-SNAPSHOT.jar (from build/libs above)
```

After reading the plugin's documentation, I can't tell how to configure it to suit these needs. Its obvious that I need to run `gradle distZip`, but as to how to actually configure it to produce the desired directory structure, it doesn't seem to provide any documentation/examples. Any ideas?

**Note**: The JAR's version is obviously `SNAPSHOT`, and is passed into the Gradle build with a `-Pversion=SNAPSHOT` command-line argument.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably not use the distribution plugin and instead just create a new custom `Zip` task. It would look something like this:

```
task buildreportZip(type: Zip, dependsOn: build) {
    classifier = 'buildreport'

    from('build/test-results') {
        into 'tests'
    }

    from('build/reports/codenarc') {
        into 'reports'
    }

    from('build/docs') {
        into 'api'
    }

    from(sourcesJar) { // or whatever you source jar task name is
        into 'source'
    }

    from(jar) {
        into 'bin'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The Gradle **[Distribution plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/distribution_plugin.html)** automatically has defaults (the problem is that the docs do not tell us the defaults, but the Gradle project default structure is what is assumed) so if your Gradle project is fairly straightforward and already using `src/main/groovy` or `src/main/java`, you typically just need to...

Use the CopySpec reversing pattern of giving your `into{}` (makes a dir) containing the contents of `from{}` , rather than the reverse, like so:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'application'

distributions {
    main {
        baseName= 'vz_sde_dm'
        contents {
            into('bin/config') {
                from 'config'
            }
            into('lib/samples') {
                from 'samples'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I did not need to define a `from{}` for my `contents{}`, but only `into{}s` that's because I am already using the default Gradle Groovy project layout and only added 2 extra folders (`config` & `samples`) under my project in Eclipse but needed those 2 folders to land into a slightly different hierarchy for my Distribution compared to my regular build folder layout.

Comment: Thank you so much , gradle's documentation is so poor that I could not found the info you've mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to make a custom layout also, and had real trouble figuring out how to exclude the project output from build/libs from the yourProject.zip/yourProject/lib directory (and excluding things in general) and putting it instead into yourProject.zip/yourProject.

After quite a few hours across multiple days of searching and poking around in the API I finally found something that worked using actual configurations of the Distribution and underlying CopySpec (documented [here](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/distribution/Distribution.html) and [here](https://docs.gradle.org/5.6.1/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/CopySpec.html), respectively for Gradle 5.6.1, you can just replace 5.6.1 with current in the URL to get the most recent API docs, 5.6.1 just happens to be the version I'm using):

```
distributions {
    main {
        baseName = appName

        contents {
            filesMatching("**/${appName}.jar", {
                if (it.getPath().contains('/lib/')) {
                    it.setPath(it.getPath().replace('lib/', ''))
                }
            })

            into('config') {
                exclude(['server.crt', 'spotbugs-exclusion-filters.xml'])
                from 'src/main/resources'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For exclusions the only thing that worked was matching on a glob pattern and specifying the correct action (to copy it to the root dist directory instead of root/lib) with a Closure through the filesMatching method of the main distribution's content CopySpec. You can see also how destination for configs is changed from the root to the root/config directory. Thanks so Thad's answer for helping to guide me to the correct build configuration, also.